# Terraform azurerm_storage_share_directory does not work with file share 'NFS'

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, nfs

We created an Azure storage account with the intention of creating an 'Azure File' to be mounted using NFS (default is SMB). Below is the Terraform code which creates a storage account, a file share and a private endpoint to the file share so that it can be mounted using NFS.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "az_file_sa" {
  name                     = "abcdxxxyyyzzz"
  resource_group_name      = local.resource_group_name
  location                 = var.v_region
  account_tier             = "Premium"
  account_kind             = "FileStorage"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  enable_https_traffic_only = false
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "file_share" {
  name                 = "fileshare"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.az_file_sa.name
  quota                = 100
  enabled_protocol     = "NFS"
  

  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.az_file_sa ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "fileshare-endpoint" {
  name                = "fileshare-endpoint"
  location            = var.v_region
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnet2.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "fileshare-endpoint-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id =  azurerm_storage_account.az_file_sa.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              =  [ "file" ]
  }

  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_share.file_share ]
}
```

This works fine. Now, if we try to create a directory on this file share using below Terraform code

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share_directory" "xxx" {
  name                 = "dev"
  share_name           = "fileshare"
  storage_account_name = "abcdxxxyyyzzz"
}
```

error we get is,
│ Error: checking for presence of existing Directory "dev" (File Share "fileshare" / Storage Account "abcdxxxyyyzzz" / Resource Group "RG_XXX_YO"): directories.Client#Get: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Get "https://abcdxxxyyyzzz.file.core.windows.net/fileshare/dev?restype=directory": read tcp 192.168.1.3:61175->20.60.179.37:443: read: connection reset by peer

Clearly, this share is not accessible over public https endpoint.

Is there a way to create a directory using 'azurerm_storage_share_directory' when file share is of type 'NFS'?

We were able to mount NFS on a Linux VM (in the same virtual network) using below code where 10.10.2.4 is private IP of the NFS fileshare endpoint.

```
sudo mkdir -p /mount/abcdxxxyyyzzz/fileshare
sudo mount -t nfs 10.10.2.4:/abcdxxxyyyzzz/fileshare /mount/abcdxxxyyyzzz/fileshare -o vers=4,minorversion=1,sec=sys
```

regards, Yogesh

full Terraform files
vnet.tf

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "yogimogi-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.10.0.0/16"]
  location            = local.region
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name

  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.rg ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name                 = "yogimogi-vnet-subnet1"
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.10.1.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet2" {
  name                 = "yogimogi-vnet-subnet2"
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.10.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name     = local.resource_group_name
    location = local.region

    tags = {
        description     = "Resource group for some testing, Yogesh KETKAR"
        createdBy       = "AutomationEdge"
        createDate      = "UTC time: ${timestamp()}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                      = local.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name       = local.resource_group_name
  location                  = local.region
  account_tier              = "Premium"
  account_kind              = "FileStorage"
  account_replication_type  = "LRS"
  enable_https_traffic_only = false


  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.rg ]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "file_share" {
  name                 = "fileshare"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  quota                = 100
  enabled_protocol     = "NFS"

  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.sa ]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "network_rule" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.sa.id

  default_action             = "Allow"
  ip_rules                   = ["127.0.0.1"]
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.subnet2.id, azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id]
  bypass                     = ["Metrics"]
}


resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "fileshare-endpoint" {
  name                = "fileshare-endpoint"
  location            = local.region
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnet2.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "fileshare-endpoint-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id =  azurerm_storage_account.sa.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              =  [ "file" ]
  }

  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_share.file_share ]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share_directory" "d1" {
  name                 = "d1"
  share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.file_share.name
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name

  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_share.file_share, azurerm_private_endpoint.fileshare-endpoint ]
}
```

error is

```
╷
│ Error: checking for presence of existing Directory "d1" (File Share "fileshare" / Storage Account "22xdkkdkdkdkdkdkdx22" / Resource Group "RG_Central_US_YOGIMOGI"): directories.Client#Get: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Get 
"https://22xdkkdkdkdkdkdkdx22.file.core.windows.net/fileshare/d1?restype=directory": read tcp 10.41.7.110:54240->20.209.18.37:443: read: connection reset by peer
│ 
│   with azurerm_storage_share_directory.d1,
│   on main.tf line 60, in resource "azurerm_storage_share_directory" "d1":
│   60: resource "azurerm_storage_share_directory" "d1" {
│ 
╵
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same having private endpoint ,having NFS enabled
and got errors as network rule is not created when NFS enabled.

[image]

As virtual network provides access control for NFS , ***`after vnet creation  you must configure a virtual network rule`***,for file share to be accessed.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "ka-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
 // tags                = local.common_tags
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "storage" {
  name                                           = "ka-subnet"
  resource_group_name                            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name                           = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes                               = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  
}  


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "az_file_sa" {
  name                     = "kaabdx"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Premium"
  account_kind             = "FileStorage"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  enable_https_traffic_only = false

   //provide network rules

network_rules {
    default_action             = "Allow"
     ip_rules                   = ["127.0.0.1/24"]
     //23.45.1.0/24
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = ["${azurerm_subnet.storage.id }"]
    
  }
  
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "fileshare-endpoint" {
  name                = "fileshare-endpoint"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.storage.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "fileshare-endpoint-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id =  azurerm_storage_account.az_file_sa.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              =  [ "file" ]
  }

  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_share.file_share ]
}


resource "azurerm_storage_share" "file_share" {
  name                 = "fileshare"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.az_file_sa.name
  quota                = 100
  enabled_protocol     = "NFS"
  
  depends_on = [ azurerm_storage_account.az_file_sa ]
}


resource "azurerm_storage_share_directory" "mynewfileshare" {
  name                 = "kadev"
  share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.file_share.name
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.az_file_sa.name
}
```

regarding the error that you got :
 `Error: checking for presence of existing Directory ... directories.Client#Get: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Get "https://abcdxxxyyyzzz.file.core.windows.net/fileshare/dev?restype=directory": read tcp 192.168.1.3:61175->20.60.179.37:443: read: connection reset by peer`

***Please note that*** :

> **VNet peering will not be able to give access to file share**. Virtual
> network peering with virtual networks hosted in the private endpoint
> give NFS share access to the clients in peered virtual networks .Each
> of virtual network or subnet must be individually added to the
> allowlist.

`A checking for presence of existing Directory` occurs  if the terraform is not initiated .Run `Terraform init` and then try to Terraform plan and terraform apply.

[image]

**References**:

1. [Cannot create azurerm_storage_container in azurerm_storage_account that uses network_rules · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2977)
2. [NFS Azure file share problems | learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshooting-files-nfs#cause-2-secure-transfer-required-is-enabled)

Comment: Tried adding "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules", doesn't work. Error: checking for presence of existing Directory "d1" (File Share "fileshare" / Storage Account "22xdkkdkdkdkdkdkdx22" / Resource Group "RG_Central_US_YOGIMOGI"): directories.Client#Get: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Get "https://22xdkkdkdkdkdkdkdx22.file.core.windows.net/fileshare/d1?restype=directory": read tcp 10.41.7.110:54240->20.209.18.37:443: read: connection reset by peer.   My guess is "azurerm_storage_share_directory" tries to access "storage" over a public end-point which is not there.

Comment: I have modified my original post with complete terraform files.